# Native.showPopup opens menu on Android

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to send an email from my game. This is the function involved:

```
local function showMailPicker()
-- Create mail options --
    local options =
    {
    to = "my@email.com",
    subject = "some text",
    body = " ",
    attachment = { baseDir=system.DocumentsDirectory, filename="file.txt", type="text" },
    }
-- Send mail --
native.showPopup("mail", options)
end
```

this function is then triggered on a touch event. but instead of getting straight to the email  program on android, I get the selection menu for Facebook, Twitter, SMS, bluetooth, gmail, ...

Can this be avoided?

Comment: see this link you can open an application using URL Scheme http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/37105-handling-url-scheme-on-android/

Comment: Thank you, will have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I would just ask, why would you want to bypass this?

I have my work email + hotmail account in the "email" application, plus a gmail account in the "gmail" app.

I would much prefer that it came up with the "which application would you like to use" when I try to send an email rather than going straight to the email app.

Comment: Its a bit confusing, that it shows also facebook, bluetooth. Then someone clicks this, but there is no content. :(

Otherwise you do have a point.